# How to solve [E0382]: use of moved value in a for loop?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, ownership

Please help me to solve the following error:

```rust
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `nd3`
  --> src/main.rs:21:21
   |
19 |     Node::Y { nd: nd3, max: max } => {
   |                   --- move occurs because `nd3` has type `std::boxed::Box<Node>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
20 |       for m in 0..max - 1 {
21 |         match recur(nd3) {
   |                     ^^^ value moved here, in previous iteration of loop
```

The code is as follows. Please don't mind that the code seems meaningless because I simplified it:

```rust
enum Node {
  X { x: usize },
  Y { nd: Box<Node>, max: usize },
  Z { Nd: Vec<Box<Node>> },
}

fn recur(nd: Box<Node>) -> Result<usize, ()> {
  match *nd {
    /// ...
    Node::Y { nd: nd3, max: max } => {
      for m in 0..max - 1 {
        match recur(nd3) {
          Ok(y) => return Ok(y),
          _ => {}
        }
      }
      return Ok(123);
    }
    _ => {}
  }
  return Ok(0);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an owned value (`nd`), and you iterate over it, and then you iterate over it again, you will get an error because it has been moved into the previous iteration of the loop.

One solution is to derive the `Clone` trait for `Node`. `Clone` is a common trait for the ability to explicitly duplicate an object:

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
enum Node {
  X { x: usize },
  Y { nd: Box<Node>, max: usize },
  Z { Nd: Vec<Box<Node>> },
}
```

Now you can clone `nd3` as you call the function again recursively:

```rust
Node::Y { nd: nd3, max: max } => {
  for m in 0..max - 1 {
    match recur(nd3.clone()) {
      Ok(y) => return Ok(y),
      _ => {}
    }
  }
  return Ok(123);
}
```

Now, you are not passing the owned value to the next iteration of the loop. Instead, you are passing an exact duplicate. Another solution would be to borrow the value. However, for smaller objects, cloning is easier.

Comment: Advice to Rust beginners: clone, clone shamelessly. Get comfortable with the language, _then_ take a big breath and dive into borrowing. Learning ownership/borrowing is hard enough that you don't want to also stumble on other issues at the same time.